# Increase max days per month in JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to decorate the JavaScript Date object to increase the numbers of day in any given month? For example, I need change the number of days in any given month to 90. So I can get something like 01/90/2016.

Comment: nope. that wouldn't make sense. you could write your own date object that violates the rules.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Makes no sense to me, probbably aliens from mars speaking *puts on tinfoil hat*.

Comment: in javascript, it is perfectly cromulent to `setDate(90)` for instance - the output will always be correct - e.g. if you have a Date object that is 1 jan 2016 and you setDate(90) - the date object will have a value of 30 march 2016

Comment: well this can be useful though there is no way to do that with js date object. And yes you can always go for your own implementation.